# Solution for inequality equation - "Cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce"

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, parametric-functions, inequalities

I am trying to solve the following inequality for $v$: $b>e^{\frac{-v}{\alpha}}\cdot \alpha + v$.
(Where I know: $b>0$, $v \in [0, 1]$, and $\alpha >0$).

However the following doesn't work: `Reduce[b>E^(-v/a)*a+v, v]`. I get the error message "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce".
`Simplify`, and `Solve` doesn't work either.

Could you think of an alternative? Or is it unsolvable?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is unlikely to be a "nice" closed-form solution for this equation, since it involves both transcendental and algebraic expressions for $v$.  However, it can be solved in terms of special functions with a bit of work.

We can make the substitution $v = \alpha x + b$ to rewrite the equation (after some algebra) as
$$
x e^x < - e^{-b/\alpha }.
$$
Now, $x e^x$ is a monotonically increasing function so long as $x > -1$:

```
Reduce[D[x Exp[x], x] > 0, x]
(* x > -1 *)
```

Given the provided constraints on $\alpha$, $v$, and $b$, we will always have $x \geq 0$.  This means that $x$ must be less than the solution to the equation $x e^x = - e^{-b/\alpha}$, and Mathematica can solve this in terms of [a special function:](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProductLog.html)

```
Solve[x Exp[x] == - Exp[-b/a], x]
(* {{x -> ProductLog[-E^(-(b/a))]}} *)
```

Thus, the solution to the inequality will be $x < W(-e^{-b/\alpha})$, where $w$ is the Lambert $W$-function (aka the product-log function.)  In terms of $v$, this then means that
$$
v < b + \alpha W(-e^{-b/\alpha}).
$$

Comment: You may have dropped a sign. Starting with `ineq1 = b > E^(-v/a)*a+v /. v -> a*x+b // ExpandAll; ineq2 = SubtractSides[ineq1, b+a*x]; ineq3 = MultiplySides[ineq2, -E^x/a, Assumptions -> a > 0 && Element[x, Reals]]` evaluates to `-E^(-(b/a)) > E^x*x`

Comment: @BobHanlon:  You're 100% correct.  Thanks for the catch.